# What exactly is the difference between a closed set and a set that is neither closed nor open?

Tags: complex-numbers, neighbourhood

So, my textbook says that a set is said to be closed if it contains all the boundary points. As for the definition of a set that is neither closed nor open, it says that the set looks somewhat like a punctured disk. They gave this set as an example: 0 < |z| $\le$ 1. What I didn't understand is, this set still contains all the boundary points. So, why was this considered to be a set that is neither open nor closed?

Comment: What is your definition of boundary point?

Comment: @noam.szyfer if you consider the neighbourhood of a boundary point, it would consist of some points that are in the set and some points that are not. I get that in this case, 0 would fit this definition of a boundary point. But, then, shouldn't the definition of closed set be changed to something like: it should contain all the interior as well as the boundary points? Because clearly, if I ever don't consider the interior points to be a part of my set, it automatically turns into a set that is neither open nor closed?

Comment: @WEDIE_18: Every set in the complex plane -- whether open, closed, both, or neither -- contains its interior points.

Comment: "Interior points" are those points that are elements of the set which are not on the boundary; they do not include points not elements of the set but surrounded by the set.

Answer (score 2):

In your example $0$ is a boundary point: the sequence $1/n$ converges to $0$, while the latter point isn't in the punctured disk. So the punctured disk isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the definition like a normal English sentence, it may seem like a closed set needs to have *just* boundary points. But with math definitions, what they're often saying is an extra property or constraint that the object needs to have.

The definition,

> a set is said to be closed if it contains all the *boundary points*

can be alternatively read as

> If you have a set, and that set contains all of its boundary points (in addition to the normal points of the set), then we call it a **closed** set

A different definition that I learnt and prefer is

> a set is said to be closed it it contains all of its *limit points*

A limit point is the limit of a sequence that uses only points from the set. In many cases, the limit is already inside the set (i.e. an interior point), but not always. For example, if you start from inside the set, and move towards the outside, the limit of this "sequence" will be a boundary point. Another reason why I prefer the limit point definition is your example. $0$ may not intuitively feel like a boundary point for the punctured point, but maybe it's easier to see it as a limit point; that is, you can create a sequence in the set whose limit is the $0$ point. But because $0$ is not included in the set, the set is not closed, even though it contains all the limits points on the outer boundary ($|z|=1$).

Comment: Actually, reading it like a normal English sentence it seems to say that it containa all its boundary points (along with any other points it might contain). Now, WTF are the "normal points" of the set? Do you really have to say that a set contains its "normal points"" What's an example of a set that **doesn't** contain all its "normal points"?